# Iniciar função Jquery quando uma div receber uma classe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma **div class="modal-load"** com um loader de contador que será mostrada quando o usuário finalizar um pagamento, mas preciso que esse contador inicie somente quando for adicionada a classe **.ativo** nela. Para isso, criei uma função no JS que roda esse load. Acredito que essa função deve ser rodada somente após a  receber a classe informada.

Testei conforme abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".modal-load").hasClass('ativo')) {
        startLoader();
    }
});
```

Quando deixo a classe já inline e atualizo a página funciona perfeitamente. Porém, quando deixo pra adicionar a classe pelo console, nada feito!

Comment: Mas aí vc está testando **se** o `modal-load` tiver a classe **ativo**, mas, vc ainda não adicionou a classe ativo.

Comment: @LeAndrade Preciso dizer que quando for adicionada a classe, ele roda a função. De que forma?

Comment: Qual evento que adiciona a classe? Nesse mesmo evento vc executa a função.

Comment: @sam pelo visto terei que fazer isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal-load").addClass("ativo");   //adiciona a classe ativo

    if ($(".modal-load").hasClass('ativo')) {  //se foi adicionada executa o loader
        startLoader();
        console.log('Sucesso!');
    } else {
        console.log("Não tem classe ativo");
    }
});
```